# Dynamic macro definition in a `foreach` loop

Tags: pgffor, csname

I created a command to dynamically define vector macros:

```
\newcommand{\makevec}[1]{\expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname{\vec{#1}}}
```

which works as I expected. But then I tried to modify this command to accept a comma separated list of symbols using the `\foreach` command defined in the `pgffor` package:

```
\newcommand{\makevec}[1]{
  \foreach \name in {#1} {
    \expandafter\def\csname \name\endcsname{\vec{\name}}
  }
}
```

The command compiles without errors, but simply fails to define the correct macros. After a bit of Googling I ran across some questions somewhat similar to mine that suggested the issue may have to do with the scope, so I tried both:

```
\newcommand{\makevec}[1]{
  \foreach \name in {#1} {
    \global\expandafter\def\csname \name\endcsname{\vec{\name}}
  }
}
```

and

```
\newcommand{\makevec}[1]{
  \foreach \name in {#1} {
    \expandafter\xdef\csname \name\endcsname{\vec{\name}}
  }
}
```

The first of these yields the same results as my initial solution, while the second produces the errors `Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }` and `Paragraph ended before \reserved@a was complete`. Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE: Here's a minimal document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand{\makevec}[1]{
  \foreach \name in {#1} {
    \global\expandafter\def\csname \name\endcsname{\textbf{\name}}
  }
}

\makevec{v}

\begin{document}

$\v$

\end{document}
```

This raises an `undefined control sequence error` at the invocation of `\v` and compiles to a blank document.

Comment: Try with `\noexpand\vec`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've added a minimal complete document to demonstrate the error.

Comment: ***Don't*** redefine `\v` or other one letter commands for accents; you'll soon regret having done it.

Comment: @egreg I don't use the accents on a regular basis and the entire point of the `\makevec` command is so I can redefine the commands on a document by document basis, so that if I know I'm going to need a certain accent in a document I can simply not redefine it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're basically doing

```
\gdef\v{\textbf{\name}}
```

which of course will raise an error because `\name` is generally undefined and, even if it were, it would most likely not be “v”. If you do

```
\makevec{v,w}
```

you'd define both `\v` and `\w` to expand to `\name`.

You need `\xdef`, but `\textbf` should be protected with `\noexpand` and, for safety, only expand once `\name`:

```
\newcommand{\makevec}[1]{%
  \foreach \name in {#1} {%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname\name\endcsname{\noexpand\textbf{\unexpanded\expandafter{\name}}}%
  }%
}
```

Beware, though, that redefining commands this way is quite dangerous. After `\makevec{v}` you'll not be able to have an author named Čech in your bibliography, because you have redefined `\v` to means something else than expected.